# Found SO question on other site with tons of advertising. Does this violate anything?

Tags: discussion

I know that other sites (w3cfacility) have explanations about using SOs' SQL dump, and from the way it looks, make a concerted effort not to "profit" from the dump.

My question is, is [THIS SITE](https://coderedirect.com/questions/38374/convert-jpg-png-to-svg-format-using-php) violating anything by posting a version of [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517497/convert-jpg-png-to-svg-format-using-php), yet using Google retargeting amongst other adverts.

Now the SO Dump is covered under the [Creative Commons](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/05/05/now-licensed-under-creative-commons/?_ga=2.165556347.593883013.1637627341-1843192620.1637627341) License, which states:

**Noncommercial**
*"You let others copy, distribute, display, and perform your work — and derivative works based upon it — but for noncommercial purposes only"*

It seems to me, that , although the site mentioned above isn't necessarily profiting from the data *directly* ...  It sure is making a profit *because* of the data, indirectly.

Also it states:

**No Derivative Works**
*You let others copy, distribute, display, and perform only verbatim copies of your work, not derivative works based upon it.*

Does this mean that the "extra" answers are not acceptable?  Or is it referring to **just the OP question**?

Is this a grey line, or am I reading too much into it?

Comment: @Nick No -- That doesn't answer the question.  SO allows the data to be used, and cloned per the license, so long as it's not "Commercial" or "Derivative Works"  .. There is no need to scrape .. They provide you with the SQL dump ..

Comment: The blog post you've linked is talking about the license for the podcasts. It's *not* talking about the license granted by users contributing content to Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange (SO/SE). For content contributed by users on SO/SE, it's a CC BY-SA license (various versions) and does *not* have either a No Derivatives (ND) nor No Commercial (NC) restriction. People can use the user contributed content on SO/SE for commercial purposes and/or make derivative works based on that content. They do have to comply with the other terms of CC BY-SA, which include attribution and Share Alike (SA).

Comment: There's no No Commercial restriction on SO content. [Someone has already sold e-books based on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273989/241919).

Comment: The SE data dump is licensed with an Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 license, not the one you quoted.  Notably, you are specifically allowed to "Adapt — remix, transform, and build upon the material for any purpose, even commercially"

Comment: Did you [report it](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) (*"What can we help you with?"* → *"Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution"*)?

Answer (score 4):

You have the wrong license for user content. It's actually licensed under some version of CC BY-SA (as indicated in the site footer and [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20517497/timeline) of every post), which does allow commercial use and derivative works.

Taking a look at the copycat site, they seem to violate the license in the same way most sites do: No attribution.

> You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. — [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)